# A homotopy problem for morphisms of dg-algebras

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, homotopy-theory, lie-algebras, simplicial-stuff

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a real finite-dimensional Lie algebra, and suppose we are given two morphisms of dg-algebras $f,g: (C^\bullet(\mathfrak g),d_{CE}) \to (\Omega^\bullet(\Delta^n),d)$, such that after post-composition with the restriction to the boundary, the morphisms vanish in positive degrees. If $n \geq 2$, is it known if there always exists an extension to a morphism of dg-algebras $H: (C^\bullet(\mathfrak g),d_{CE}) \to (\Omega^\bullet(\Delta^n\times [0,1]),d)$, such that for $t = 0, t=1$ we get back $f,g$ respectively, and post-composing with the restriction to the boundary $\partial\Delta^n\times [0,1] \hookrightarrow \Delta^n\times [0,1]$ vanishes in positive degrees?

Here $C^\bullet(\mathfrak g) = \text{Sym}(\mathfrak{g}^\vee[-1])$, the differential $d_{CE}$ maps $\xi \in \mathfrak{g}^\vee$ to 
$$
d_{CE}\xi = \xi \circ [-,-],
$$
and is extended as a derivation.

The motivation for this is attempting to show that the simplicial set of dg-morphisms from $C^\bullet(\mathfrak g)$ to the exterior algebra of the $n$-simplex has vanishing homotopy groups in degrees $\geq 2$.

Thanks in advance!